# Custom Option Math Operators - Multiply and Divide

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options

Magento 1.8

Are there multiply and divide operators? I can only add in minus (-) or plus (+). [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field must take a *number*, as the message suggests. `+` and `-` only work because "+4" is identified as "4" and "-4" is a negative number.

However, you can change "Price Type" from "fixed" to "percentage" and enter for example "400" to multiply the price by 4